# Photoelectric effect - Two different types of ionisation as evidence?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

My current understanding is:

The evidence for Electrons being particles is ionisation.

I am not sure about the next part so please correct me if I am wrong.

Evidence for Light being a particle is the photoelectric effect:
I understand that there is a type of "ionisation" where the energy state of an electron is infinity (Completely removed from a metal, where n=infinity). Is this the same thing as the second line?

In terms of an explanation for the second line, would the photoelectric effect work for it still as a photon is technically a particle/Quanta of energy?

Thanks.

Comment: The "second line"?

Comment: "The evidence for Electrons being particles is ionisation."